# useState React Hook set method does not update state immediately in onChange()

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update form through useState React Hook

```
const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState({
    username: {
        value: "",
        validation: {
            required: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false,
    },
    password: {
        value: "",
        validation: {
            required: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false,
    }

})
```

My input element is using onChange Event which calls a function. Here key is either username or password according to the for loop

```
<input className={classes.input_element} type="text" name="{key}" value={loginForm[key].value} onChange={event => inputChangedHandler(event, key)} required />
```

inputChangedHandler definition is as follows:

```
const inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const updatedField = updateObject(loginForm[inputIdentifier], {value: event.target.value, touched: true, )})
    const updatedForm = updateObject(loginForm, {[inputIdentifier]: updatedField,})
    setLoginForm(updatedForm)
    console.log(updatedForm)
    console.log(loginForm)
}
```

In the above code, in the last 3rd line, I am setting the actual value of loginForm with the updatedForm. But when I am logging the updatedForm and loginForm to the console, both are giving different outputs.

updatedForm

```
{username: {…}, password: {…}}
password: {value: "", validation: {…}, valid: false, touched: false}
username: {value: "a", validation: {…}, valid: true, touched: true}
__proto__: Object
```

loginForm

```
{username: {…}, password: {…}}
password: {value: "", validation: {…}, valid: false, touched: false}
username: {value: "", validation: {…}, valid: false, touched: false}
__proto__: Object
```

In the input field, I am picking the value from the loginForm only and there I am getting the actual updated value. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a useEffect with dependency updatedForm

```
useEffect(()=> {
    //do what every you want when  updatedForm changes
},[updatedForm])
```